# How to get HTML of page which consist of JavaScript only

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a values of Selenium versions available for download from this page: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html just as test values. But i can't use API's which allow to find elements (like Jsoup) with Xpath or CSS because HttpURLConnection returns me a JS source of page. So my Q is how i can get full HTML of that page so i could at least parse the versions of selenium?? My restriction is only JAVA code can be used!

Comment: I don't see any Javascript for this page...

Comment: Start from `https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com`. This will return you a XML document. Which would be easier to parse.

Comment: Thank you  @SubOptimal  !!! Was helpful!